# How to use Translatable from Symfony Console Command

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to find documentation for retrieving translated records via translatable (StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle) when executing a console command from Symfony. This command call a service that retrieves data from Doctrine using the

```
$query->setHint(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HINT_CUSTOM_OUTPUT_WALKER, 'Gedmo\\Translatable\\Query\\TreeWalker\\TranslationWalker')
                ->setHint(\Gedmo\Translatable\TranslatableListener::HINT_TRANSLATABLE_LOCALE, $lang);
```

If I call this service from a URL (a Controller) translatable works fine, but if I run the command from the CLI , Translatable is not fired or fails to force the locale ($lang). Any idea to solve that?

Comment: just an idea, completely unsure about this, but i know there is a translatableListener somewhere,   maybe it is not listening to console events ...  (had a similar issue with another bundle)

Comment: Sound promising. How did you fixed the other bundle?

Comment: by making the listener also listen to the appropriate commands ...  https://github.com/BranchBit/AsyncDispatcherBundle/blob/master/Resources/config/services.yml      (this particular thing, had to fire on kernel.terminate, but i had forgotten it also had to fire on console.terminate, or it would not work in CLI),   again,  i am not sure this is your issue,   but it could be,   check your TranslatableListener

Comment: Where is the variable `$lang` in your snippet coming from?